# TSQL - Trying to use variable with IF EXISTS() Function for simple SP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

Our company runs a MS Access Frontend and SQL Backend, and I'm trying to provide a stored procedure for the frontend that would allow it to have access to T-SQL's IF EXIST, instead of using DCount to improve performance.  To do this I need to be able to pass the SELECT statement to the stored procedure, and so far I have the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].IfExists 
@selectStatement varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (@selectStatement)
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 0
END
GO
```

which doesn't work because it doesn't like the @selectStatement instead of a hardcoded statement.  Not sure how I can do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"instead of using DCount to improve performance"* - Are you *sure* that this will improve performance or is this largely a guess?

Comment: From what every Access programming text I've read tells me, the domain functions are bad on performance to begin with, and even if it was on the same level as executing count(*) it's still slowing than TSQL's IF EXIST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql to achieve this

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

e.g.:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQl NVARCHAR(MAX), @retVal INT

SET @DynamicSQl = 'select @retVal = 1 from (' + @selectCommand + ') t'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQl, N'@retVal INT OUTPUT', @retVal output

IF (@retVal = 1)
  RETURN 1
ELSE
  RETURN 0
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL looks like the way to go, I'm trying to figure out how to properly rephrase what I have into Dynamic SQL though, since the SELECT statement is really just feeding the IF EXIST, and that's what I really care about.

Comment: use if exists in the dynamicSql variable and set retVal, then check the value of retVal

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, had to use a parameterized version of this, but without the pointing to the link and the sp_executesql, I wouldn't have known where else to go, thanks.