# Is it possible to change declared variables in a SQL query using C#, without parsing the command string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

Is it possible to change the variables in a SQL query using C#, without parsing the command text?

Most specifically, in the following code, is it possible to change the parameter `@report_date` in `cmd` without parsing through or changing the string?

The code should successfully prompt

```
string conn_info = "Data Source=db_hostname;Initial Catalog=db_name;User Id=user;Password=pass;Connection Timeout=15;";
string cmd_txt = "DECLARE @report_date DATE = '3/4/2015' SELECT @report_date;";
using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_info) ) {
    conn.Open();
    using ( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd_txt, conn) ) {
        var param = new SqlParameter("@report_date", SqlDbType.Date);
        param.Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        var o_info = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show(o_info.ToString());
    }
}
```

When this runs, I get:

`The variable name '@report_date' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.`

Of course I can simply remove the declare statement, but then I wouldn't be able to run the query independently - and would have to modify existing queries.  I simply want to know if my attempted approach is possible, and if so, how.

Comment: Since your `cmd_txt` Declares `@report_date`, no, you can't change it without modifying the `cmd_txt`.

Comment: It may be possible to add a null coalesce and wrap it in a nested query, so that the Declare is set to the default value if the parent's argument is DBNull. This should let you pass a value while keeping compatibility.

Comment: I tried doing a coalesce, but coalesce won't work with an undeclared variable.

Comment: sounds like you're left with Dynamic SQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073842/tsql-trying-to-use-variable-with-if-exists-function-for-simple-sp

Comment: I don't think Dynamic SQL would work here either, since I believe it would still require `@report_date` to be declared, even if there wasn't any value set for it, and even then, I'm not sure how I would be able to set `@report_date` after declaration.

Comment: The problem is that it is declared With  A Value, not that it is declared. My mistake in communicating that part.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to change it even if it's declared without a value.  I'm thinking that the answer to my question is simply, `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you pass a date to SQL command, only to have it return the same date?  if you will always be looking for current date, you could just use:

```
select getdate()
```

as the sql command.

Comment: I was just using that as an example.  The date is used to query a specific range of data, which is variable.