# How to execute sub query in if exists condition?

Tags: sql, subquery

```
declare @qry varchar(100)
declare @cnt int
set @qry = ' where '

if exists( select * from  ARTICLE_MANAGE +@qry+ article_id=65)
BEGIN
select top 1* from  ARTICLE_MANAGE order by article_id desc
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select * from  ARTICLE_MANAGE order by article_id desc
END
```

This is the query. '@qry' is changed by what we passed to the query

Comment: sorry i cant get it.

Comment: See [SQL “if exists…” dynamic query][1]


or

[TSQL - Trying to use variable with IF EXISTS() Function for simple SP][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710260/sql-if-exists-dynamic-query
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073842/tsql-trying-to-use-variable-with-if-exists-function-for-simple-sp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @cnt INT;
set @qry = ' where '
DECLARE @ExeQuery VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @ExeQuery='if exists( select * from  ARTICLE_MANAGE '+@qry+' article_id=65)
BEGIN
select top 1* from  ARTICLE_MANAGE order by article_id desc
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select * from  ARTICLE_MANAGE order by article_id desc
END'
 EXEC(@ExeQuery)
```

Comment: It is working fine.. this is the exact solution what i looking for..thank you RAJ.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are building a `dynamic sql` and `EXISTS` limits to only `subquery`.

You can have the functionality of `EXISTS` with `count(*)`

```
declare @qry varchar(100) 
declare @cnt int 
set @qry = ' where '

declare @sql_qry nvarchar(1000) 
set @sql_qry = 'select @Cnt = COUNT(*) from  ARTICLE_MANAGE' + @qry + 'article_id=65'

DECLARE @Count AS INT
EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@Cnt INT OUTPUT', @Cnt=@Count OUTPUT

if exists(@Count > 0) BEGIN
    select top 1* from  ARTICLE_MANAGE order by article_id desc
END
ELSE BEGIN
    select * from  ARTICLE_MANAGE order by article_id desc
END
```

Comment: Thank You praveen for your help.